# C++ HTTPS request failed using cURL 7.55.1

Tags: curl, c++17, libcurl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

std::size_t write_callback(char* in, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string* out) {
    std::size_t total_size = size * nmemb;
    if (total_size) {
        out->append(in, total_size);
        return total_size;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string readBuffer;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
        std::string mainurl = "https://www.atmaple.com/Test.txt";
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, mainurl.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;
}
```

I'm having an issue when trying to do a HTTPS request. When I use curl in a console it works fine, but it fails to work in C++. It was working before, but now there's an SSL error.

```
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x7011c8; line 1654 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITRESOLVE handle 0x7011c8; line 1700 (connection #0)
* family0 == v4, family1 == v6
*   Trying 31.170.160.123:443...
* STATE: WAITRESOLVE => WAITCONNECT handle 0x7011c8; line 1782 (connection #0)
* Connected to www.atmaple.com (31.170.160.123) port 443 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x7011c8; line 1848 (connection #0)
* Marked for [keep alive]: HTTP default
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x7011c8; line 1866 (connection #0)
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Marked for [closure]: Failed HTTPS connection
* multi_done
* The cache now contains 0 members
* Closing connection 0
* Expire cleared (transfer 0x7011c8)
```

I'm just trying to get the data from the page. In this test example, it should return a number.
Here it is in a console:

```
curl --ssl https://www.atmaple.com/Test.txt
3,711,488
```

This is the version of I am using installed from vcpkg:

```
curl --version
curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL
Release-Date: 2017-11-14, security patched: 2019-11-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding SSL

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
```

Comment: This did not solve the issue. Although, I went about using a ca-bundle.crt from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html and it's returning the correct data from the site. Although, originally I did not have to do this which is why I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did some searching and found this website: https://pranavprakash.net/2014/09/27/using-libcurl-with-ssl/

There's a section called LibCurl with SSL and he downloads a CA cert from this website: https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html

I downloaded the cacert.pem and renamed it to ca_bundle.crt (or whatever else you want to name it and added this to my code:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "ca-bundle.crt");
```

and it returns the correct data from the link.

```
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x1174928; line 1654 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITRESOLVE handle 0x1174928; line 1700 (connection #0)
* family0 == v4, family1 == v6
*   Trying 31.170.160.123:443...
* STATE: WAITRESOLVE => WAITCONNECT handle 0x1174928; line 1782 (connection #0)
* Connected to www.atmaple.com (31.170.160.123) port 443 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x1174928; line 1848 (connection #0)
* Marked for [keep alive]: HTTP default
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: none
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x1174928; line 1866 (connection #0)
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=atmaple.com
*  start date: Feb 25 03:04:46 2021 GMT
*  expire date: May 26 03:04:46 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.atmaple.com" matched cert's "www.atmaple.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x1174928; line 1885 (connection #0)
> GET /Test.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: www.atmaple.com
Accept: */*

* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x1174928; line 1940 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => PERFORM handle 0x1174928; line 2061 (connection #0)
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Last-Modified: Tue, 27 Oct 2020 22:25:29 GMT
< Etag: "9-5f989e59-7aa76bf0011c68c2;;;"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 9
< Date: Mon, 05 Apr 2021 23:39:30 GMT
< Server: LiteSpeed
< Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
<
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x1174928; line 2251 (connection #0)
* multi_done
* Connection #0 to host www.atmaple.com left intact
* Expire cleared (transfer 0x1174928)
```

**3,711,488 <- what is being returned from Test.txt via website.**

Maybe it wasn't working as intended or I was using an older version of cURL. But my code was working fine before which is why I was confused. It shows the same information as if I were to just use:

> curl -ssl https://www.atmaple.com/Test.txt

Now I have to have this line and the .crt in order for it to make the HTTPS request.